# Selector nth-child producing odd results in CSS

Tags: css

I need to select my number of items is odd. No matter an element class "box-media2"

Anyone has any idea/advice about this issue a part of adding a class "odd" ?

```css
.box-media:nth-child(2n+1) {
  color: red;
}

.box-media2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
```

Comment: nth-child() supports even and odd. `.box-media:nth-child(even)` or `.box-media:nth-child(odd)`

Comment: Could you clarify: what's not working in the example you posted?

Comment: @alexanderbird an example, red Test as odd and class "box-media2" display none.

Comment: The whole question is a bit confusing. .box-media2 will NEVER be shown, because 1.) it has no content, thus no box will be rendered, and 2.) it's set to `display: none`. :nth-child() does not negate an element, just because it is hidden.

Comment: Pseudo-classes, like `:nth-child`, select elements, not classes of elements. Using a class acts like a filter and makes the selection more restrictive.

Comment: @kfriend .box-media2 will NEVER cannot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `.box-media:nth-child(4n+1)` to select odd `.box-media` children.

```css
.box-media:nth-child(4n+1) {
  color: red;
}

.box-media2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
<div class="box-media">Test</div>
<div class="box-media2"></div>
```

That's because `.box-media:nth-child(2n+1)` searches for odd children (including `.box-media` and `.box-media2`), and applies styling to odd children that have a `box-media` class, which is always true in your case.

More about `:nth-child` selector on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Comment: BIG @5aledmaged THANK YOU!!!